# A browser to achieve multiple login in Shiro

Tags: shiro

I have a web app which have 2 parts: front part and backend part. Both part need a login page for users. Members need to use /signin to login front part. Admins need to use /admin/signin to login backend part.How to achieve, thank you

Comment: You can make one think that from the front-end use same login page for both user and admin from back-end side redirects them from type of that user.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to happen when the user logs in via the incorrect /signin page.  I'm guessing members should not be allowed in, but what if admin's login to the member's page?

Honestly, the simplest thing is to just hide/show an 'admin' link when an administrator logs in (for example only render the link when a user as an 'admin' role or permission.

Comment: Thank you,@Brian Demers if the background login succeeds, then the front is not logged in, the front will need to be redirected to the login page, in other words: they are two different session of the key, I know that if the direct use to authenticate the session is very simple, such as: session ( "menber", menber); session ( "admin", admin), shiro can achieve this function?

Comment: You could, but not out of the box. By default, Shiro puts it's SecurityManager in the ServletContext, so you would need to override the 'EnvironmentLoaderListener' to create multiple instances, and then deal with setting up two different [Shiro filters](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.3.x/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/servlet/ShiroFilter.java).  This could probably be done with less work by using Guice or Spring and scoping the objects, 

You may also want to think about splitting up your app into two different services.

Comment: Thank you,@Brian Demers，Can you give an instance?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using two different SecurityManagers and two different SessionManagers (using different session cookies). 

But I would still suggest writing two different smaller focused applications instead of one monolithic one, or controlling access via permissions or roles.